# App to web video calling using Sinch

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am working on a project which is created as an application and as a website. This application includes app to app video calling as well as app to web video calling also. I have successfully implemented app to app calling, but how can i implement app to web calling. 
My project includes user1 and user2. User1 calls user2 on app. App to app calling is successful,but user2 can be logged in from website also, then in this case i have to accomplish a video call from app to web. Please help me by some code for how can  i achieve this using Sinch library. Thank you.

Comment: @ShivamOberoi Please check this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278922/why-is-the-sinch-call-quality-from-mobile-app-to-browser-very-poor    This says that it is possible

Comment: Yes its possible...you can talk to Sinch support regarding this..

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to set a video call from phone to web using Sinch lib.
Code for this is same as for phone to phone calling. There is no change in the code in android.